# **Kafka** Bi-directional sync between datacenter across regions

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a deployment where we are using kafka to send messages from the services. But we need to have master Kafka in all the regions. So once the message is pushed in 1 data center, it should be synced in other. And when it is done in other data center again it should be synced back. Mirror Maker can offer sync from 1 to other, but how do I achieve the bi-directional sync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Master-Master kind of replication is not available in Kafka, Kafka MirrorMaker can only mirror in one direction.

*Why ?*
Kafka MirrorMaker is basically a combination of producer and consumer transferring events from one DC to another and during this process the offset of mirrored topic will be different from one in the source cluster. Now if we wanted to have bi-directional will have to keep track of messages produced at one end, which is hard(not worth) without tweaking too much in all your consumers and producers. 
There is no way to run make mirrormaker to do master-master kind of replication in Kafka, it will only end up in loops.

If you want to achieve your requirement you might have to keep data center specific topic and aggregate them to a master topic.

Say you want to produce messages to topicA from both DC1 and DC2.

- Have topicA-DC1 in DC1 and topicA-DC2 in DC2. And have master topic topicA in both DC1 and DC2.
- Your mirromaker should have aggregate messages from topicA-DC1 and topicA-DC2 to master topic topicA in both data centres.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think too now that the way should be to run multiple mirror makers on both master and slave to maintain same data.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason MirrorMaker is one-directional is to avoid "loops" of the same event being read from site A into site B and then synched from B back to A.

If you look at [this blog post](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/running-kafka-scale) (specifically "tiers and aggregation") a solution is to have "local" and "aggregate" topics, where you use MM to read from the local topic into remote aggregate topic(s)

Comment: the solution mentioned will work, but it will add up to the number of servers. Lets say we have to limit the number of servers running kafka, is there a way to run mirror on both the data centers and sync?